# Splitting of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given a non-empty array, if there is a place to split the array so that the sum of the numbers on one side is equal to the sum of the numbers on the other side return the length of the two arrays as an array but if there is no place to split the array, return -1

```
canBalance([1, 1, 1, 2, 1]) → [3,2]
canBalance([2, 1, 1, 2, 1]) → -1
canBalance([10, 10]) → [1,1]

function canBalance(array) {
//Type your solutions here

}

module.exports = canBalance;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make two variables, and add and subtract each item in the array until they are equal.

```js
function canBalance(array) {
  let start = 0, end = array.reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0);
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    start += array[i];
    end -= array[i];
    if (start == end) {
      return [i + 1, array.length - (i + 1)];
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

console.log(canBalance([1, 1, 1, 2, 1]));
console.log(canBalance([2, 1, 1, 2, 1]));
console.log(canBalance([10, 10]));
```

Answer (score 0):

loop through the array from the first (index 0) to the one before the last (length -1) since you want to check only until the second last to compare against the last one.
you can use slice to get the array minus the one element being iterated each time and use a reducer to get the sum

```
const reducer = (a, c) => a+c;
function canBalance(array) {
  var result = [];
  var arr = [];
    for(var i=0; i<array.length - 1; i++){
      arr.push(array[i]);
      var leftover = array.slice(i+1,array.length);
      if(arr.reduce(reducer) === leftover.reduce(reducer)){
         result.push(arr.length);
         result.push(leftover.length);
      }
    }
   return result.length > 0 ? result : -1;
}
```